# Variable data is lost during use

Tags: c#

### Background

I am building a mailer that accepts headings, labels, and data from a form then combines multiple sections into the email body and forwards it. in order to facilitate that, I created a class `MailSection` that includes a string, two lists of strings, and a bool. After adding the data to the class, I add that instance of the class to a list of that class and start the next section. Unfortunately, clearing the data before starting the next section clears the data from the previous instance, as well.

### Sample Code

```
public class Mail Section
{
  public string SectionHeading {get; set;}
  public List<string> Labels {get; set;}
  public List<string> Data {get; set;
  public bool Table {get; set;}
}
```

elsewhere in the code of the page.

```
List<string> labels = new List<string>();
List<string> data = new List<string>();
List<MailSection> mailSections = new List<MailSection>();

//section 1
labels.Add("Name");
data.Add("Some Customer");
labels.Add{"Email");
data.Add("Some.Customer@somedomain.com");
mailSections.Add(new MailSection("Customer Info",labels,data,false));
//Here, the data is still intact.
labels.Clear();
data.Clear();
//Here, I expect labels and data to be clear. 
//Unfortunately, this also clears the data in any instance of mailSection
```

### What I have tried

I have tried making the MailSection class disposable, and I have tried using a separate instance of `MailSection` that I would add and reset.

Comment: You are reusing the same lists. Unless you make a copy of the list in the MailSection, all sections reference  the same list which you keep clearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes because all instances of MailSection are pointing the same instance of labels and data.

Solution:

Create new instances of

```
List<string> labels = new List<string>();
List<string> data = new List<string>();
```

everytime for a new instance of MailSection